# How to make swift listView roulette animation

Tags: ios, swift, listview, animation, uicollectionview

Good day! I am trying to implement such animation feature. Maybe you saw something like this. List view with cells that behave like roulette. I know how to resize cells in collection view while scrolling, but i need that some cells go under another.
Please help, if you know some tutorials or give a hint which methods should i use.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZNp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Take a look at this. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=card

Comment: @GlennPosadas ohh thank you never saw this site, really cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this yourself with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, but I find those very confusing.

I've used a framework called iCarousel in the past:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

It's very well done, although it's fairly old and it looks like it hasn't been maintained.